# Pass variable from table field

Tags: python, web2py

Is there a way to pass field and their value instantly at the time of writing the form from model to controller? Unlike after click submit or other

If not how can I detect value in one field and change other field option according to the value at the time of writing the form itself?

Comment: You'd have to use Ajax. Maybe try jQuery

Comment: Can u show me example with field being 'list:string' type. Based on that field, generate another field.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to work out first a minimum sample when you get stuck and maybe you can open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is "Live Search"
[Slices: Live Search](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1378/ajax-live-search-auto-complete)

Also Per field outfocus update would be:

[This Slice](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1983/auto-update-db-records-behaviour-per-input-field-on-release)